# Stripping the last line/footer from a csv file in Python 2.7

Tags: python

```
import csv
import operator
import os
import sys

with open('test.csv', 'r') as cvsfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in f:
        line = [line:-1]
        print (line)
```

=====

Tried the above
I am trying to strip the last line from a csv file before sorting. I am able to strip the header with a next() command but am unable to strip the footer.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to do `line[:-1]`?

Comment: Oops yes.. that was a mistake in typing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip first/last line, you can convert the csv.reader to list and then use `[1:-1]` on it. For example:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    
    for line in list(f)[1:-1]:  # [1:-1] to strip first/last line from csv
        print (line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing a with a big dataset, `list(f)[1:-1]` will load the entire set into memory at once and then make of copy of that list without the first and last element of the original list. To keep using the generator so that only one line is loaded into memory at a time,

```
import csv
import operator
import os
import sys

curr = None
next_line = None
with open('test.csv', 'r') as cvsfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(f) # remove first line
    try:
        curr = next(f)
        next_line = next(f)
        while True:
            print(curr)
            curr = next_line
            next_line = next(f) 
    except StopIteration: 
        pass
```